# Help with 1-dimensional random walk

Tags: random

I would like to simulate the evolution of a bankroll of a 2 player game where you have the probability of winning p. If a player wins, the bankroll grows by 1 unit minus a fee that each player pays, let's say the fee is r.  So, when a player wins a game the bankroll grows by 1-2*r, since each player pays the fee.  If a player loses the game obviously the bankroll diminishes by 1 unit.

In the example below p=0.517 and the fee is such that the player wins 0.959 units. 
When I generate the plot I am surprised to see that the line decreases while I would expect that it would increase.   Am I generating the NestList incorrectly?  Thanks.

```
RandomWalk[n_] := 
   NestList[(# + If[RandomReal[] >= 0.517, 0.959, -1]) &, 0, n]

ListPlot[RandomWalk[3000], Joined -> True
```

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with this question, since it rests on a simple misunderstanding, I am going to vote to close it as "too localized".

Answer (score 7):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I've found `RandomChoice` is generally the most "intentful" of the random functions. With `RandomChoice`, your code would be something like:

```
randomWalk[n_, p_: .517] := NestList[# + RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {.959, -1}] &, 0, n];
```

And for example, if you wanted a 2-to-1 ratio, you would write:

```
randomWalk[n_] := NestList[# + RandomChoice[{2, 1} -> {.959, -1}] &, 0, n];
```

---

For this problem, notice there is no state involved, so you can generate a random stream independently and then Fold over it:

```
randomWalk[n_, p_: .517] := FoldList[Plus, 0, RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {.959, -1}, n]];
```

And if you *really* want to impress the girls:

```
randomWalk[n_, p_: .517] := Accumulate@RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {.959, -1}, n];
```

Comment: (+1) But why impress only the girls?

Answer (score 6):

You just have to turn the inequality around:

```
RandomWalk[n_] := 
 NestList[(# + If[RandomReal[] <= 0.517, 0.959, -1]) &, 0, n]

ListPlot[RandomWalk[3000], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

The probability `.517` is supposed to mean that the first argument of the `If` gets executed. Since the interval of `RandomReal` goes from `0` to `1`, the part of the interval *below* `p` has the (length) measure given by `p`.

Comment: oh right! thanks.